# Suppose $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson} (N)$ where $N\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, What is the P.G.F of $X+N$?

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions, poisson-distribution

I have tried conditioning on $N$ and I obtained that:

$$G_X(Z) = \exp\left(\lambda\left(e^{Z-1}-1\right)\right).$$

I then used the property that states that $G_{X+N} = G_X(Z)*G_N(Z)$. But I was unsure as to whether you could do this as it is not clear in the question that $N$ and $X$ are independent.

Comment: *Idea where to begin this one*: Can you compute the PGF of $Y_n+n$ where $Y_n$ is Poisson with parameter $n$?

Comment: Hint: Try conditioning on the value of $N$.

Comment: can I use the property that says $G_{X+N}(Z) =G_X(Z)*G_N(Z)$ ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $N$ independent?